# Whats the difference between the ::after and :after?

Tags: css

I find I use the `p:after` and `p::after` I can get the same effect.(line 5 you can find it)

```css
p:after {
  content: "- add_after";
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<p>I am a boy。</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg。</p>

<p>this is my home</p>
```

So, whats the difference between the `:after` and `::after`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Resource :https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Every browser that supports the double colon (::) CSS3 syntax also supports just the (:) syntax, but IE 8 only supports the single-colon, so for now, it's recommended to just use the single-colon for best browser support.

:: is the newer format indented to distinguish pseudo content from pseudo selectors. If you don't need IE 8 support, feel free to use the double-colon.

Answer (score 0):

This seperate pseudo elements from pseudo classes.

You can read the further detail about difference between pseudo classes and pseudo elements at

http://www.d.umn.edu/~lcarlson/csswork/selectors/pseudo_dif.html